# Buttons CSS styling not working on mobile

Tags: css

I've been doing the classic build a calculator using vanilla javascript. It's looking and working fine on laptop and on inspector appeared to be fine on the different devices.

However, when I put live and opened it on my phone, the styling for the buttons has completely gone. Rather than the buttons being full heigh within their designated divs, for example, they are now much much thinner and rounder.

I can't work out what I've done wrong on the CSS or need to add in. Any help  please appreciated!

The repo with the stylesheet is here: https://github.com/thejoefriel/calculator

And you can view the calculator live here: https://thejoefriel.github.io/calculator/

Comment: I think its normal, because its responsive, why not set a fix width to your container and the buttons

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@media`, please use the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. Otherwise the css styles may not apply in real mobile devices.

Comment: Unfortunately this has just made it look worse in mobile?

Comment: Then the styling you have done might be the issue, this meta tag helps you to apply the styles you have added under `@media`. If you don't use this meta tag, then the styles won't apply.